# How to get an Acknowledge when an email is sent from Salesforce

Tags: email

How to get an acknowledge when an email is sent from my salesforce org.

Can I get the receipt of delivery/ failure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view by follwoing two steps.

> 1. You can view the HTML activity history in Salesforce itself.
> 2. You can see the email log.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Setup--> administration setup --> Monitoring --> Email Log Files and Request an Email log.

> Email logs describe all emails sent through salesforce.com and can be
> used to help identify the status of an email delivery. Email logs are
> CSV files that provide information such as the email address of each
> email sender and its recipient, the date and time each email was sent,
> and any error code associated with each email. Logs are only available
> for the past 30 days.

Look at this doc to understand the codes from the email log
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_logs_format.htm&language=en_US

> R - Reception The email was successfully received.
>
> D - Delivery The email was successfully sent.
>
> T - Transient Failure The email transmission was delayed. Salesforce
> will retry delivery over a 24-hour period. The first retry occurs five
> minutes after the first transient failure, the second occurs ten
> minutes after that, the third twenty minutes after that, and so on.
>
> P - Permanent Failure The email could not be delivered.

Comment: In this case can we get the delivery notification to our mail?

Comment: the email log is sent over to the email on your user account.

Comment: That log contain only which are the mails are sending form my account. But I need to notify who are all open the mail when sending form my org.

Comment: nope that log gives u all emails sent from Salesforce.com. The text I have highlighted is from salesforce documentation

Comment: Yes. Its shows the status but I need to get the mail. Ex: If I send the mail to our customer from salesforce, I will get the receipt mail when open that customer. Is there possible in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit to the other answers:

1. You can activate [email bounce management](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h3P7AAI) - it will add flags to Contact, Lead & Person account. Read about it in help, it's awesome and it [displays nice exclamation](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glFFAAY) mark if there are problems.
2. [This is a bit old blog post](http://www.shellblack.com/administration/email-deliverabilty-and-html-status-reports/) but nicely covers various reporting possibilities
3. If you want to instantly know that the email went out without the hassle of email logs (it won't help you if it was delivered & opened though!) you can automatically add a BCC (hidden copy) address to all communications. Each user can decide for himself if it's something he/she wants but there's also a global setting. Check the help for "Compliance": https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_compliancebcc.htm&siteLang=en_US (sadly the options are mutually exclusive).